# When will the actual v-table be accessed?

Tags: c++, inheritance

**Background** 
I know how the compiler generates the virtual address table (v-table). So to make things simple for me to explain, lets take this simple example,

```cpp
class Entity {
public:
    Entity() {}

    virtual void Initialize() {}
};

class Player : public Entity {
public:
    Player() {}

    virtual void Initialize() override final { ... }
};
```

So now we make an instance of `Player` and assign its address in the `Entity` class pointer,

```cpp
Player player = {};
Enity* pEntity = &player;
```

Now I'm going to call the `Initialize` method, one using the `player` variable and the other in `pEntity` variable.

```cpp
player.Initialize();    // Call 1.
pEntity->Initialize();  // Call 2.
```

So my question is, 
When will the v-table of the class `Player` get accessed? Is it in `Call 1` or is it in `Call 2` or is it in both the cases?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since `player` is a concrete object with an actual `Initialize` member function it can be called directly without virtual dispatch. There's simply no polymorphism in that case. For polymorphism (and virtual dispatch) you *must* go through a pointer or reference to a base-class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So does that mean that a `Player` class pointer will still not use virtual dispatch?

Comment: @john What I mean is something like `Player* pPlayer = &player;` and `pPlayer->Initialize();`

Comment: A call through `Player` class pointer (`Player*`) will most likely be devirtualized by a compiler because `Initialize()` is marked with `final`.

Comment: @D-RAJ Technically the `Player` vtable will first "*get accessed*" when the `player` object is constructed. That's assuming there *is* a vtable at all, which the language does not specify or require. Not sure why you'd prefer to think of this in terms of vtables, rather than in terms of language specifications.

Comment: I'm a little curious, why do you wonder about this? Is it plain curiosity (which is fine, but please state that)? Or do you have another problem leading to this question? If you have another problem, please ask about that directly instead, and we can better help you solve it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No its purely based on curiosity. Thankfully I didn't come across a problem linked to this ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compilers are free to do whatever they want. They can implement everything without vtables, so take all the below with a grain of salt.

```
Player player = {};
player.Initialize();
```

When you define an object with `class` type, the compiler knows that the static type is equal to the dynamic type. So it is likely to call the required method directly. It can even inline and optimize-out the call. But this behavior is not required - the compiler may decide to play it dumb, and use vtable to call the method.

```
Enity* pEntity = &player;
pEntity->Initialize();
```

When you define an object with a pointer (or reference) type, the compiler may assume it's a pointer (or reference) to a base class, and access its vtable during the call. However, many compilers do *devirtualization* in cases where they can determine the runtime type with certainty. It's easy to determine the runtime type here because there is no code between the creation of the object and the virtual call.

---

The `final` specifier can help the compiler devirtualize calls. In the simplest case, it's not even necessary; it would help in the following code:

```
Player* pPlayer = VeryComplexPlayerFactory();
pPlayer->Initialize();
```

Here, it's easy to see that `pPlayer` will point to a type derived from `Player`, so there is only one implementation option for the `Initialize` method.

---

Devirtualization is an optimization; some compilers let you disable it (`-fno-devirtualize`). You should disable it if you want to explore generated machine code for vtables.